# Fixed point set as an inverse limit

Tags: category-theory, group-actions, limits-colimits

We can regard a group action on a set as a functor
$$
F: BG \to Set\;,
$$
where $BG$ is the category with one object and a morphism for each element of $G$, and $Set$ the category of sets.

Now, is it true that $\lim_{\leftarrow} F$ gives the fixed points of the action? 
If so, by duality, can we say that $\lim_{\rightarrow} F$ gives the orbit space?

The reason why I'm asking is that I've heard the statement for modules (but without proof), and I was wondering how general this is.

Comment: It is true, but I wouldn't say it's "by duality"...

Comment: Why is it true? I really cannot see it.

Comment: It's one of those things where you just have to calculate concretely.

Comment: Uhm, calculate what exactly? Where do I start?

Comment: There are formulas that explicitly construct limits and colimits in $\mathbf{Set}$. Use them.

Comment: Oh yes, I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: Not understanding the notation, but curious. What inverse and direct systems does the letter $F$ refer to?